# How can I pass a variable from one React component to another and trigger a re-render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to export a variable to a seperate component and have that component re-render based on the value of the variable

```
export function exportName(name){
    searchName = name;
    console.log("You Logged", searchName);
    indexJS.renderThumbs(searchName);
    setSearchName(searchName);  
}
```

it logs the correct value but how do i pass it into here, and make this component re-render:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as flickr from './flickr.jsx';
import Modal from './modal.jsx';

class Thumbs extends React.Component {
    state = {
        searchName: "",
        photos: [],
        fullImage: "",
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData() {
        //console.log(this.state.searchName)
        flickr.getInteresting(this.photoReady, this.state.searchName);
    }

    photoReady = (photos) =>{
        this.setState({photos}, () =>{
            //console.log(this.state.photos);
        })  
    }

    setSearchName = (name) => {
        this.setState({searchName: name}, () =>{
            console.log(this.state.searchName)
            this.fetchData();
        })
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div className='pictures'>
                {this.state.photos.map((photo, index)=>{
                    return(
                        <figure key={index} data-full={photo.full} data-title={photo.title} onClick={() =>{this.handleClick(photo.full)}}>
                            <img src={photo.file} alt={photo.title}/>
                            <figcaption>{photo.title}</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    );
                })}
                {this.modal()}
            </div>   
        );  
    }

    handleClick = (fullImage) =>{
        //console.log(fullImage);
        this.setState({fullImage});
    }

    modal = () =>{
        if (this.state.fullImage === "") return null;

        //console.log("modal has full image");
        return <Modal fullImage = {this.state.fullImage}/>;
    }

}

export default Thumbs;
```

this is my index.js where renderThumbs() comes from:

```
export function renderThumbs(searchName){
    if (!thumbsRoot) {
        thumbsRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(mainDiv);
      }
      thumbsRoot.render(<Thumbs searchName={searchName}/>);
};
```

I can't seem to get Thumbs or renderThumbs to recognise that the variable searchName has been updated.